# I'm getting the "AndroidX dependencies" error with android.useAndroidX enabled

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, androidx

I am getting the following error while trying to build my android app:

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> This project uses AndroidX dependencies, but the 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled. Set this property to true in the gradle.properties file and retry.
> The following AndroidX dependencies are detected: androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0, androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0, androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0, androidx.core:core:1.0.0, androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0, androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0, androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0, androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0, androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0, androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0, androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0, androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.0.0, androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0, androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0, androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0, androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0, androidx.media:media:1.0.0, androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0, androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0, androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0, androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0, androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0, androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0, androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0, androidx.print:print:1.0.0

I modified the project's gradle.properties file and set "android.userAndroidX" to true. But everytime I try to build again it goes back to false automatically.
Is there any chance that gradle.properties is being overwritten by any other task during the build?

Thanks!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Presumably you are using `cordova-android@8` (type `cordova platform ls` to find the platform versions in your project).

So you have 2 options:

1. Update to `cordova-android@9` which implicitly supports AndroidX:

   ```
   cordova platform rm android && cordova platform add android@9
   ```

   In your **config.xml** add the following line:

   ```
   <preference name="AndroidXEnabled" value="true" />
   ```

   More details here: [cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2020/06/29/cordova-android-9.0.0.html)
2. Add [cordova-plugin-androidx](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-androidx) to your Cordova project, which persistently sets the native AndroidX flags for `cordova-android@8`:

   ```
   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx
   ```

If after adding one of these your project still fails to build, it may be because it contains Cordova plugins whose native Android code references the legacy Android Support Library (to which AndroidX is the successor).
To resolve this, you can add [cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter) to your project which will dynamically patch the source code of those plugins to migrate them to AndroidX:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
```

Comment: Great, glad to help! Please accept this as the correct answer for the benefit of other users.

Answer (score 13):

In your **config.xml** add the following line:

```
<preference name="AndroidXEnabled" value="true" />
```

More details here:
[cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2020/06/29/cordova-android-9.0.0.html)

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was downgrading Cordova Social Sharing plugin to 5.6.8

```
cordova plugin add  cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing@5.6.8
```

(before doing that remove the previous version of this plugin, then remove all platforms, then reinstall all platforms)

Comment: This worked, for me, I don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

Add to gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

In AndroidStudio Click: File->Invalidate Cashes / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I set it to true directly, but it is changed everytime I try to build. I don't have AndroidStudio installed. I'm building through command line.

Comment: I'm not sure the cause of the problem,[this blog](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-to-androidx-tip-tricks-and-guidance-88d5de238876) may help.

Comment: You can change them in platforms/android/cordova/lib/configGradlePropertiesParser.js in the this._defaults objects

Answer (score 0):

You can try `cordova prepare android` if you are using latest cordova it will patch your source files and also update gradle.properties

Answer (score 0):

first Open your **Project gradle scripts>> then open gradle.properties** And Finally paste this two line code

```
android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my Android platform to 9.1.0 today as well as the plugins I use. However compilation of my projects started to output `Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED` error and `This project uses AndroidX dependencies, but the 'android.useAndroidX' property is not enabled.`. I've been looking for several reasons and tried different solutions proposed here on SO, but the most accurate idea was given by @Guy Sela who suggested a plugin can use the new AndroidX dependencies and this was the reason. So before you try to use the `AndroidXEnabled` property in Cordova config or plugin adapter for the AndroidX (which are both non-recommended by Cordova at the time of 9.1.0 Android platform) look for a plugin you recently updated.

Answer (score -2):

I was stuck for 2 days than I got this
you just need to install these two plugin nothing else you'll have to do

1. add plugin to enable AndroidX in the project

   ```
   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx
   ```
2. add plugin to patch existing plugin source that uses the Android Support Library to use AndroidX

   ```
   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter
   ```

Comment: This is exactly the same solution as in [Kangudie Muanza - Killmonger's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64972426/2227743).