# android.useAndroidX= false overriding value when build ionic android

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid

I am build an android app in ionic 4. when I changing the value of
android.useAndroidX= true to android.useAndroidX= false, after running command to build ionic cordova build it again sets to android.useAndroidX= true. I don't know from where it is overriding the value

Comment: Have you found any workaround? Setting ``<preference name="AndroidXEnabled" value="false" />`` in config.xml is totally pointless, everytime the APK is built gradle.properties is reset.

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade cordova-android.

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android@10
```

You have more answers on this post [63831903](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63831903/im-getting-the-androidx-dependencies-error-with-android-useandroidx-enabled)